# SQL COUNT from othertable

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, subquery

Let's say I have two tables. One called Clients and One called Prizes

Clients and Prizes are related to eachother with a one to many relationship.
For each time a client receives a prize it will be inserted in the Prizes table as an individual record.

How Can I determine with a query how many Prizes a certain client has received?

I want it to display as such: Clients.Clientname, [Number of prizes in Prizes table as integer number]

I have had a lot of struggle doing this.

I am trying to make this in Ms Access 2007

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: If you have had a lot of struggle, what have you tried?  This is a pretty simple SQL query (one join and one aggregation).

Comment: I have tried using a subquery like this: SELECT Clients.ClientID, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Prizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the table structure:

```
Clients

    ID
    ClientName


Prizes

    ID
    ClientID
    Description
```

You could do:

```
SELECT c.Clientname, COUNT(p.ID) AS NumberOfPrizes
FROM Clients c
LEFT JOIN Prizes p ON c.ID = p.ClientID
GROUP BY c.Clientname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.Clientname, 
       count(p.id) as prices_count
from clients c
left join prices p on p.client_id = c.id
group by c.Clientname
```